# unable to pass datetime to google appengine from jsp form

Tags: jsp, google-app-engine, servlets

I am trying to save the Date and Time taking it through the user from a frontend created in JSP and received by the java servlet. 
Following is the code of my JSP:

```
<form role="form" action="/abc" method="post">

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">

                    <input type="hidden" name="div_bvg" type="number" class="form-control" value="0" required/>
                </div>
            </div>

            Enter the Details: 
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">End Date</span>
                    <input name="div_enddate" type="datetime-local"  class="form-control" required/>
                </div>

            </div>

            <a href="/dashboard" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>

        </form>
```

Following is the receiving through my servlet

```
 DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
 String sdate = request.getParameter("div_enddate").trim();
 DateTime enddate = new DateTime(edate);
 Entity election = new Entity("example");
 election.setProperty("EndTime", enddate);


Transaction txn = datastore.beginTransaction();
datastore.put(txn,election);
txn.commit();

if (txn.isActive()) { //if trnasaction is still active (which means not committed properly then it rollbacks)
    txn.rollback();
  }
```

Following is the error I get upon submitting

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid date/time format: 2020-01-01T01:00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear to me how are you taking that time in your front end but you are passing an invalid time format to Java.

In your front end you are using this format:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm
```

Java expect this format:

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS
```

You have 2 options

1. You can convert the time format in your frontend to match java date format. This is recommended because you remove workload from your backend.
2. Parse the date in your backend as a string and then remove the "T" and then use it as a date i.e.

Java time format conversion:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
SimpleDateFormat output = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date d = sdf.parse(time);
String formattedTime = output.format(d);
```

Comment: Thank you, found the problem I had different date format and was giving a different one.